# Can Mods Convert a Comment to a Question?

Tags: feature-request

[Moving money from my savings account to an IRA - why am I paying taxes on it?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/21379/moving-money-from-my-savings-account-to-an-ira-why-am-i-paying-taxes-on-it) has a (closed) comment that looks like a question in its own right, and @MrChrister commnted to that point. Does the SE SW permit mods to flip a comment to a question, instead of asking the poster to do so?

Comment: No tools to do that.  The other issue that is often such an answer / question / comment conversion should be re-written and thought of before becoming a new question.

Comment: @MrChrister: Your comment above should actually have been an answer, sorry can't filp it :)

Comment: @Dheer - lol.  I wasn't 100% I was right.  Your joke is not lost on me though...

Answer (score 3):

No tools to go from comment -> question.

We can go from Answer -> Comment as that is a frequent newbie use of stack exchange to "answer" in an attempt to say "thanks".

Comment: Thanks! I just flagged this situation earlier, hoping that move was possible.